# creating directed graphs in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, matrix, directed-graph

I am trying to implement a simple code in php in which I have to create a directed graph from the sql data base. I just have to represent the E-R diagram connections in form of a directed graph. Can someone help me?
Here is my beginner's code. This code is yet not working. Suggest improvisations
This code basically is trying to create a sample graph.

```
<?php
require_once 'Structures/Graph.php';`

$directedGraph =& new Structures_Graph(true);
$nonDirectedGraph =& new Structures_Graph(false);

require_once 'Structures/Graph/Node.php';

$nodeOne =& new Structures_Graph_Node();
$nodeTwo =& new Structures_Graph_Node();
$nodeThree =& new Structures_Graph_Node();
$directedGraph->addNode();
$directedGraph->addNode();
$directedGraph->addNode();

$nodeOne->connectTo($nodeTwo);
$nodeOne->connectTo($nodeThree);

$nodeOne->setData("Node One's Data is a String");
$nodeTwo->setData(1976);
$nodeThree->setData('Some other string');

print("NodeTwo's Data is an integer: " . $nodeTwo->getData());

$nodeOne->setMetadata('example key', "Node One's Sample Metadata");
print("Metadata stored under key 'example key' in node one: " . $nodeOne->getMetadata('example key'));
$nodeOne->unsetMetadata('example key');

// Nodes are able to calculate their indegree and outdegree
print("NodeOne's inDegree: " . $nodeOne->inDegree());
print("NodeOne's outDegree: " . $nodeOne->outDegree());

// and naturally, nodes can report on their arcs
$arcs = $nodeOne->getNeighbours();
for ($i=0;$i<sizeof($arcs);$i++) {
    print("NodeOne has an arc to " . $arcs[$i]->getData());
}
?>
.
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)? and [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)?.

Comment: What means "not working"?

Comment: "not working" is neither an error message or a problem description. Please provide an example of where it fails and how you would like help. Also, it would help to show your SQL table structure as well - if that's got a flaw, then anything you write in PHP will need a rethink anyway.

Comment: Problem solved. Thankyou for the concern though.